# 'addEventListener' and 'onclick' working only on 'window' Element and NOT any other Element(such as button)

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, addeventlistener

I am trying to make Snakes and Ladders Board game in JavaScript and trying to add 'onclick' or 'addEventListener' events to the buttons of the game. But when I am trying to add them to my buttons through `pb.addEventListener("click",p1click);`, they are NOT working. But when I am adding these events to my "window" element through `window.addEventListener("click",p1click);`,they ARE working fine. What is the reason behind this problem? I am attaching the working code snippets below to properly explain my problem.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
canvas.width = innerWidth;
canvas.height = innerHeight;
margin=100;
const c=canvas.getContext('2d');
const img=document.getElementById("board");
c.drawImage(img,0,0,canvas.width-margin,canvas.height-margin);
  pb=document.getElementById("player");
  p1=document.getElementById("text1");
    function p1click(){
        p1.innerHTML="Dice Rolled!";
    }
    
    //window.addEventListener("click",p1click);//Working...
    
    pb.addEventListener("click",p1click);//Not Working!!!
```

```css
/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
#col1 {
    float: left;
    margin-top: -75px;
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  #col2 {
    float: left;
    margin-top: -75px;
    width: 33.33%;
    margin-left: 33.33%;
  }
  #col3 {
    float: left;
    margin-top: -75px;
    /*margin-top: -75px;*/
    width: 33.33%;
    margin-left: 66.66%;
  }
  
  .row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas>
            <img id="board" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/colorfull-snake-and-ladder-game-vector-id577332576"></img>
        </canvas>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column" id="col1">
                <button type="button" id="player">Player</button>
                <p id="text1" style="display:inline; margin-left: 50px;">Dice Value:</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column" id="col2">
                <button type="button" id="reset">Reset Game</button>
                <p id="text3" style="display:inline; margin-left: 50px;">Reset?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column" id="col3">
                <button type="button" id="computer">Computer</button>
                <p id="text2" style="display:inline; margin-left: 50px;">Dice Value:</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <script src="./index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your canvas seems to cover your buttons

Comment: Like others said, the canvas is covering the buttons and hence we cannot click on them. You need to adjust your widths or else put the “z-index” property on the buttons.

Comment: I am trying to set z-index of button and/or its containers. But they are still being covered by the canvas. They work only if I remove margin-top attribute from the columns. But I do not want to do it. Can you share the solution code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the buttons have to be stacked on top of the canvas? Could they not just be above the canvas element and you handle the canvas size accordingly (such as subtracting margin from the innerHeight as I do just below)

You can then also remove the margin-tops. See the snippet below, it works:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
margin=100;
canvas.width = innerWidth;
canvas.height = innerHeight - margin;
const c=canvas.getContext('2d');
const img=document.getElementById("board");
c.save();
c.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
c.restore();
c.drawImage(img,0,0,canvas.width-margin,canvas.height-margin);
  pb=document.getElementById("player");
  p1=document.getElementById("text1");
    function p1click(){
        p1.innerHTML="Dice Rolled!";
    }
    
    //window.addEventListener("click",p1click);//Working...
    
    pb.addEventListener("click",p1click);//Not Working!!!
```

```css
/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
#col1 {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  #col2 {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    margin-left: 33.33%;
  }
  #col3 {
    float: left;
    /*margin-top: -75px;*/
    width: 33.33%;
    margin-left: 66.66%;
  }
  
  .row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column" id="col1">
                <button type="button" id="player">Player</button>
                <p id="text1" style="display:inline; margin-left: 50px;">Dice Value:</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column" id="col2">
                <button type="button" id="reset">Reset Game</button>
                <p id="text3" style="display:inline; margin-left: 50px;">Reset?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column" id="col3">
                <button type="button" id="computer">Computer</button>
                <p id="text2" style="display:inline; margin-left: 50px;">Dice Value:</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <canvas>
            <img id="board" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/colorfull-snake-and-ladder-game-vector-id577332576"></img>
        </canvas>
        <script src="./index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

**Edit**: If you really want to stack the row above the Canvas, you can use position absolute on the row along with a high z-index to put it above the canvas. See the snippet below:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
margin = 100;
canvas.width = innerWidth;
canvas.height = innerHeight - margin;
const c = canvas.getContext('2d');
const img = document.getElementById("board");
c.save();
c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
c.restore();
c.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width - margin, canvas.height - margin);
pb = document.getElementById("player");
p1 = document.getElementById("text1");

function p1click() {
  p1.innerHTML = "Dice Rolled!";
}

//window.addEventListener("click",p1click);//Working...

pb.addEventListener("click", p1click); //Not Working!!!
```

```css
/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */

#col1 {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}

#col2 {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  margin-left: 33.33%;
}

#col3 {
  float: left;
  /*margin-top: -75px;*/
  width: 33.33%;
  margin-left: 66.66%;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.row {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column" id="col1">
      <button type="button" id="player">Player</button>
      <p id="text1" style="display:inline; margin-left: 50px;">Dice Value:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id="col2">
      <button type="button" id="reset">Reset Game</button>
      <p id="text3" style="display:inline; margin-left: 50px;">Reset?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id="col3">
      <button type="button" id="computer">Computer</button>
      <p id="text2" style="display:inline; margin-left: 50px;">Dice Value:</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <canvas>
            <img id="board" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/colorfull-snake-and-ladder-game-vector-id577332576"></img>
        </canvas>
  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution :) . I have kept the buttons after the canvas. Just decreased the height of the canvas as you suggested. Now, the buttons are working fine. But I am still wondering if there is any way to adjust z-index along with allowing the canvas to cover full screen. But for now, your solution will work for me.

Comment: You could put the row class in a `position: absolute` (or a container covering it) and put its z-index high so that it's above the canvas!

Comment: Tried. But not worked.

Comment: I just edited my solution and posted a second snippet below with absolute positioning and z-index. Check it out! It has the buttons row above the canvas. I added a border so you could see where it is in contrast to the background canvas

Comment: Its Working! Thanks!! I will use the updated solution